# problem - "404 error" for localhost:8081/question/allQuestions

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

application properties:

```
# Database Connection Properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quizmaker
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Corona@123

# Specify the JDBC driver for MySQL
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

# Hibernate properties
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update 

# # Connection pool settings
# spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=20000
# spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5
# spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=20
# spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=300000

# Logging SQL statements
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
server.port=8081
```

[image: postman picture result]

i tried to excute above program..but i got same error for both @Getmapping and @PostMapping

```
{"timestamp":"2024-02-11T11:22:56.192+00:00",
"status":404,
"error":"Not Found",
"path":"/question/allQuestions"}
```

controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/question")

public class QuestionController{

    private QuestionService questionService;

    public QuestionController (QuestionService questionService)
    { 
        this.questionService = questionService;
    }
    // ------Read Operation----
    @GetMapping(path = "/allQuestions")

        public List<com.example.model.Question> getAllQuestions () {
        return questionService.getAllQuestions();
    }
    @GetMapping(path = "/category/{category}")
    public List<com.example.model.Question> getQuestionsByCategory (@PathVariable String category) {
    return questionService.getQuestionsByCategory( category);
    }
    //------Create Operation---
    @PostMapping(path = "/create")
    public String createQuestion (@RequestBody Question question) {
    return questionService.createQuestion ((com.example.model.Question) question);
    }
}
```

[postman result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6aUN.png)

**it doesn't show any error on terminal...still i didn't get desired output**

Comment: It is likely that you are missing something in the path or base path. Could you please share the implementation of the GET and POST methods?

Comment: @jarus  uploaded QuestionController...if any modification is needed...let me know

Comment: As I suspected, the path of the GET method is incorrect. You have defined it as "allQuestions", but in your Postman request, it is "allQuestion," which is causing this error.

Comment: @jarus I changed and tired in Postman still i get the same "404" error. Check the above postman results.

Comment: I don't see the controller implementation. Could you please share the updated one?

Comment: @jarus I shared the Controller part.Please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path of getAllQuestions() has been defined with `/allQuestions` but you invoke API with `/allQuestion` API path.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check your controller to investigate the cause of the 404 error. The error typically occurs when your application is unable to find the requested resource, such as the /question/allQuestion endpoint, in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Did you correctly register the paths in the controller?

For example:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/question")
public class QuestionController {

    @GetMapping(path = "/allQuestion")
    ResponseEntity<?> getAllQuestions() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks...I tired still hasn't resolved